# Infinite while loop pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, while-loop

Am I running an infinite loop? If so, how might I resolve the issue?

The code is the following:

```
new_exit_date, new_exit_price = [] , []
high_price_series = df_prices.High['GTT']
entry_date = df_entry.loc['GTT','entry_date']
window_price_series = high_price_series[high_price_series.index >= entry_date]
while len(window_price_series) >= 63:
    window_high_series = window_price_series[-63:]
    last_date_of_window = window_high_series.index[0]
    entire_hist = high_price_series[high_price_series.index <= last_date_of_window]
    if window_high_series.max() != entire_hist.max():
        new_exit_date.append(window_price_series.index[-64])
        new_exit_price.append(window_price_series[-64])
        break
    else:
        window_price_series = window_price_series[window_price_series.index >= window_high_series.idxmax()]
if len(window_price_series) < 63:
    new_exit_date.append(window_price_series.index[0])
    new_exit_price.append(window_price_series[0])
```

`high_price_series` is a Pandas series of prices for the stock GTT.
`entry_date` gives the date we enter a buy order for the stock GTT. Let's suppose that we enter on 2018-03-02. So `entry_date` takes the value `'2018-03-02'`. Suppose that within a window of 63 trading days, GTT makes a new historical high, that is `window_high_series.max() == entire_hist.max()` on 2018-03-26, then what I want to do is update `window_price_series` to begin from 2018-03-26, and run the check again if GTT makes a new historical high in a time span of 63 trading days from 2018-03-26.

`high_prices_series` looks like

```
Date
2021-04-01  1.89
2021-03-31  1.90
          ...
2018-03-26  62.32
2018-03-25  62.35
          ...
2018-03-02  49.00
```

that is the index is in descending order.

I'm unsure where is the code running into the infinite loop. Would it be in the
`entire_hist = high_price_series[high_price_series.index <= last_date_of_window`?

Please comment if you require more information.

Comment: @jezrael sure, thanks

Comment: I submitted a new post for the same question...

Comment: @jezrael thanks so much for helping! I did some further testing - the same original code worked and then failed (very strange) when I restarted the python file... I know that the logic wasn't wrong tho

Answer (score 0):

Use `window_price_series = window_price_series[window_price_series.index > window_high_series.idxmax()]` instead. A `>` sign instead of `>=`